# RSparkling Spark Error on YARN (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: water.fvec.frame)

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark, h2o, sparklyr

I'm trying to set up my R environment to run h2o algorithms on a YARN cluster.
(have no access to the internet due to security reasons - running on R Server)

Here are my current environment settings:

- spark version: 2.2.0.2.6.3.0-235 (2.2)
- master: YARN client
- rsparkling version: 0.2.5
- sparkling water: 2.2.16
- h2o version: 3.18.0.10
- sparklyr version: 0.7.0

I checked the h2o_version table for all the version mappings, but still get this error when I run the code:

```
options(rsparkling.sparklingwater.version = "2.2.16")
options(rsparkling.sparklingwater.location = "path to my sparkling water.jar") 

Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "path to my spark") 
Sys.setenv(SPARK_VERSION = "2.2.0") 
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR = "...") 
Sys.setenv(MASTER = "yarn-client") 

library(sparklyr) 
library(h2o) 
library(rsparkling) 

sc = spark_connect(master = Sys.getenv("SPARK_MASTER"), spark_home = Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), version = Sys.getenv("SPARK_VERSION")) 
h2o_context(sc) 

R Server ERROR output: 
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundExecption: water.fvec.Frame 
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) 
...
```

Things I've tried:

- Follow the instructions [here](http://github.com/h2oai/rsparkling/blob/master/inst/examples/using-sparkling-water-in-YARN.Rmd)
- Reinstalling the h2o package and multiple retries
- Trying different versions of h2o and sparkling water (3.18.0.5 and 2.2.11 respectively)

I am sure it would not be a version error since I've been matching them according to h2o_release_table() as shown. Please help or guide me to a solution.

Comment: just to keep track of where this question has been posted in case it gets answered in the other location: https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/issues/916

Answer (score 0):

(Problem Solved)

Turns out the there was another **sparkling-water-core_2.11-2.2.16.jar** file within the */jar/* directory in my spark-client path, and therefore was being directly read in as a part of the Classpath Entries, causing the conflict. (Confirmed through Spark UI Environment tab) I've played around with the Spark Classpath without any luck, so I had to request the file to be removed.

After doing that, the problem was fixed. I've also tested this out with different versions of the sparkling water JAR and the h2o R package. (sw 2.2.11 & h2o 3.18.0.5, sw 2.2.19 & h2o 3.20.0.2)

```
options(rsparkling.sparklingwater.version = "2.2.16")
options(rsparkling.sparklingwater.location = "path to my sparkling water.jar") 

Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "path to my spark") 
Sys.setenv(SPARK_VERSION = "2.2.0") 
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR = "...") 
Sys.setenv(MASTER = "yarn-client") 

library(sparklyr) 
library(h2o) 
library(rsparkling) 

sc = spark_connect(master = Sys.getenv("SPARK_MASTER"), 
                   spark_home = Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), 
                   version = Sys.getenv("SPARK_VERSION")) 
h2o_context(sc)
```

A bit a awkward answering my own question, but I hope this helps anyone else in need!